# Trying to initialize test environment with v9 firestore sdk using jest

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, firebase-security

Im trying to set up my testing environment to test my security fules with firestore. I've copied this code from https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests#before_you_run_the_emulator

```js
let testEnv : RulesTestEnvironment;

beforeAll(async () => {

    testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
        projectId: "demo-project-1234",
        firestore: {
            rules: fs.readFileSync('firestore.rules', 'utf8'),
        },
    });

});
```

However, I'm getting this error.

> The host and port of the firestore emulator must be specified. (You may wrap the test script with firebase emulators:exec './your-test-script' to enable automatic discovery, or specify manually via initializeTestEnvironment({firestore: {host, port}}).

Anyone know how to solve this?

**EDIT**

I tried adding host and port to my running emulator like so

```js
let testEnv : RulesTestEnvironment;

beforeAll(async () => {

    testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
        projectId: "comment-section-e9c09",
        firestore: {
            rules: fs.readFileSync('firestore.rules', 'utf8'),
            host:'localhost',
            port:8080
        },
    });

});
```

Now it seems to be able to connect to my emulator, but when I try to fx clear the database like

```js
test("sefse", () => {
    testEnv.clearDatabase()
})
```

I get the following error

> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: The host and port of the database emulator must be specified. (You may wrap the test script with 'firebase emulators:exec './your-test-script'' to enable automatic discovery, or specify manually via initializeTestEnvironment({database: {host, port}}).".] {

Comment: Hi @Boris Grunwald, could you please check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure) and see if helps.

Comment: We’re you able to get past this?

Answer (score 4):

I give u a "mocha-based" starting point:
security.test.js:

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { assertFails, assertSucceeds, initializeTestEnvironment } from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";
import { doc, getDoc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

let testEnv;
let unauthedDb;

describe("general database behaviour", () => {

before(async () => {
  testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    projectId: "demo-project-1234",
    firestore: {
      rules: readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: "8080"
    },
  });
  unauthedDb = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext().firestore();
});

after(async () => {
  await testEnv.cleanup();
});

  it("should let read anyone the database", async () => {
    await testEnv.withSecurityRulesDisabled(async (context) => {
      await setDoc(doc(context.firestore(), 'data/foobar'), { foo: 'bar' });
    }); 
    await assertSucceeds(getDoc(doc(unauthedDb, 'data/foobar')))
  })
  it("should not allow writing the database", async () => {
    await assertFails(setDoc(doc(unauthedDb, '/data/foobar'), { something: "something" }))
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the firestore port and rules path in your firebase.json file like so?

```json
"emulators": {
  "firestore": {
    "port": 8080
  }
},
"firestore": {
  "rules": "./rules/firestore.rules"
}
```